# Constructive and destructive interference in De Broglie matter waves

Tags: waves, wave-particle-duality

I'm a little confused about matter waves and especially interference.

$\lambda = h/p$

The denominator is momentum and is thus reliant on mass.  If we assume that the property holds for particles only, then I run into some problems with constituent "particles".  What I mean by that are objects normally considered to be point masses, that are really made of several other particles.  Examples being protons, neutrons, atoms, and occasionally molecules.

Let's take a $ ^4He$ atom as our example.  It consists of 2 protons and 2 neutrons.  This gives it a mass of $4.002602amu$ or $6.6464 * 10^{-27}kg$.  Let's give it a nice non-relativistic velocity of $15m/s$.  The calculation of its De Broglie wavelength is trivial.

$\lambda = \frac{h}{6.6464 * 10^{-27} * 15} = 6.646\mathrm{nanometers}$

Now, lets take one of the constituent protons in the helium atom and calculate its wavelength.

$\lambda = \frac{h}{1.6726 * 10^{-27} * 15} = 26.426\mathrm{nanometers}$

Similar result for neutrons:

$\lambda = \frac{h}{1.6749 * 10^{-27} * 15} = 26.390\mathrm{nanometers}$

Its apparent that the difference in these is substantial.  The main question I have is how these differences can coexist?

List of questions:

Assuming that the difference is a result of incorrect application of the formula.

1. Why do these values differ, is it not appropriate to take the wavelength of something that is bonded to the larger whole?
2. If not then why not? Why does the binding energy prevent the nucleons from having their own waves?
3. Do we have a better model that computes for the wavelength of a particle being attracted or repelled in an arbitrary electromagnetic or strong/weak field?
4. Reasons other than binding energy as to why you can not apply the formula to an individual nucleon?

Assuming that the difference is a result of constructive/destructive interference.

1. What happens to the binding energy, does its existence in the mass term of the atom make the calculation for the wavelength of the atom an approximation?
2. What happens to the little bit of the wave that might not constructively interfere but destructively interfere because the nucleons are not perfectly on top of each other?  Does that make the atom wavelength only an approximation?
3. If the atoms wavelength is only an approximation then do we have a better model that takes into account all of the interference and produces a more accurate wavelength for a particle with constituents?
4. Has this been used to try to determine the binding energy of quarks, is this something that has been tried?

Comment: I think this is a good question. There have been double slit experiments with Buckyballs that are obviously very composite molecules.

Comment: The de Broglie wavelength only applies to free particles. So the free particle in question is the nucleus, as opposed to any single neutron or proton. Bound neutrons have their de Broglie wave 'used up' to interact via the strong nuclear and electromagnetic force?